# How to update key value in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

This is what I have so far:

```js
var onepage = [{
    name: 'Custom Design',
    hours: 5
  },{
    name: 'Premium Theme',
    hours: 2
  },{
    name: 'SEO',
    hours: 5
  },{
    name: 'Backlink Building',
    hours: 6
  },{
    name: 'Article Writing',
    hours: 7
  },{
    name: 'Copywriting',
    hours: 3
  },{
    name: 'Development',
    hours: 8
  }
]

window.onkeyup = keyup;

var numberofPages;

function keyup(e) {
  numberofPages = e.target.value;
  newHours = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < onepage.length; i++) {
    var totalHours = numberofPages * onepage[i].hours;
    newHours.push(totalHours);
  }
  console.log(newHours);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Number of Pages" id="pages" value="1">
```

The user inputs # of pages and the it gets multiplied by `hours` and pushed into the array `newHours` and from there I want to update the original object array hours.

I'm not sure how to `update` it, or does it make sense to create a new array of objects?

Comment: Can you specify what you want to update? Every hours property in all objects? Multiplied by number of pages?

Comment: `newHours = onepage.map(chapter => ({ chapter.name, hours: chapter.hours *= numberofPages}));`

Comment: @baao Let's assume the user enters in 10. The newHours array will be [50, 20, 50, 60, 70, 30, 80]. I then want to update the original array of objects "Hours" to have those numbers.

Comment: @user3330820 If you use `onkeyup`, you need to keep the original hours separately. Otherwise the calculated hours keep growing while you type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the array directly without creating a newArray. Please note, that updating directly `hours`of the original array will lead to undesired results. Hence, added a new property `calculatedHours`

```js
var onepage = [{name: 'Custom Design',hours: 5},{name: 'Premium Theme',hours: 2},{name: 'SEO',hours: 5},{name: 'Backlink Building',hours: 6},{name: 'Article Writing',hours: 7},{name: 'Copywriting',hours: 3},{name: 'Development',hours: 8}];

window.onkeyup = keyup;

var numberofPages;

function keyup(e) {
  numberofPages = e.target.value;
  newHours = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < onepage.length; i++) {
    onepage[i].calculatedHours = numberofPages * onepage[i].hours;
  }
  console.log(onepage);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Number of Pages" id="pages" value="1">
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, the fact that this happens in `onkeyup` will give undesired results.

Comment: @ChrisG - Agreed. Updated answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, adding a new property works all the same to me and this did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Just do a simple forEach loop like shown below. I've created it so that it gets updated once the user presses the enter key (13) inside the input. I'd suggest to put the listener on the input, not on the window in real code.

```js
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  if (e.keyCode !== 13) return;
  onepage.forEach(el => el.computed = el.hours * e.target.value);
  console.log(onepage);
})
```

```html
<input id="foo">
<script>
var onepage = [
    {
        name: 'Custom Design',
        hours: 5
    },
    {
        name: 'Premium Theme',
        hours: 2
    },
    {
        name: 'SEO',
        hours: 5
    },
    {
        name: 'Backlink Building',
        hours: 6
    },
    {
        name: 'Article Writing',
        hours: 7
    },
    {
        name: 'Copywriting',
        hours: 3
    },
    {
        name: 'Development',
        hours: 8
    }
]
</script>
```